# Double click Trigger event to clear textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would need to add an event handler for a double-click event of a text box. I'm trying to trigger the click event of clear button from the handler for the double-click event. This should

> clear text from the textbox that is double-clicked

The code for the clear button works from the following code:

```
$("#clear_entries").click(function () {
$("input[type=text]").val("");
$("input[type=text]").after("");
$("#email_address1").focus();
});
$("#email_address1").focus();
});
```

I am trying to use the shortcut for trigger method using $("#clear".click();

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#myTarget").on("dblclick", function() {
    // Do stuff...
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8RRaL/)

Comment: Thanks! The following code worked:                                   $("input:text").dblclick( function(){
 $(this).val('');
});

Comment: @user3492649 great, Good luck! Accept the answer if you don't have any more questions.